# how to send an array over socket and then get each item in python

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

Below is my server.py and client.py. So I want to print each item in the array separated by a new line. 
Server.py:

```
import socket

listener = socket.socket()
listener.bind(("",12345))
listener.listen()

while 1:
    conn = listener.accept()
    sock = conn[0]

    encoded_message = sock.recv(2048)
    while len(encoded_message) > 0:
    message += encoded_message.decode() + "\n"
    encoded_message = sock.recv(2048)

print(message)

encoded_message = message.encode()
sock.send(encoded_message)
sock.shutdown(1)

sock.close()
```

client.py:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(("localhost",12345))

testing_strings = ["A123 45",
               "L65 78",
               "E486",
               "D4 1 0",
               "E1.0",
               "S1.0",
               "S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 -1e-15",
               "Not a number",
               "S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 0",
               "S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 G 1 1e-15"]

for c in testing_strings:
    encoded_message = c.encode()
    sock.send(encoded_message)

sock.shutdown(1)

encoded_message = sock.recv(2048)
while len(encoded_message) > 0:
    message += encoded_message.decode()
    encoded_message = sock.recv(2048)

print(message)
sock.close()
```

But I always get

```
A123 45L65 78E486D4 1 0
E1.0
S1.0
S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 -1e-15
Not a number
S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 0
S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 G 1 1e-15
```

It seems like the first three items always go together and the rest works just fine. I want to separate them out and print each line. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.
Expected output:

```
A123 45
L65 78
E486
D4 1 0
E1.0
S1.0
S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 -1e-15
Not a number
S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 -25 1 0
S0 2 -945 1689 -950 230 G 1 1e-15
```

Comment: post the final expected output

Comment: I just edited it. Thanks

Comment: can you show how are running your both scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How each piece of message doesn't have the same size, so I think that the best way to accomplish this is some structured communication using serialization like XML, JSON, etc.

If you don't want use serialization, you can use a start and end tag or unique symbol, like a pipe "|", for each time you send the data.
So, in the server code, you should concatenate all message and finally split the final content into a list.

```
separator = "|".encode()
for c in testing_strings:
    encoded_message = c.encode()
    sock.send(separator)
    sock.send(encoded_message)
```

I wrote an answer to a similar question, you can see here:

[Simple Python Server Client File Transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775320/simple-python-server-client-file-transfer/46777554#46777554)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Hey it works. Thanks a lot. Actually I'm trying to pass each item in the array to calculate the polynomials. And I was testing to see how the data come in.Now I know it works fine. Thanks